How to generate lattice by integrating over curves on a modular form domain plot?
I was watching this video (2:30 of https://youtu.be/zLEyIT_BCgk?si=ji5NyjR7vcwzaNxi ).

Here in the video he said that to get the lattice , we just integrate over the curve(silver line) and we will get the black lattice.
My question is, is it possible to this in Mathematica and if yes can someone share some example code?
Thanks

Please take a look at ContourIntegrate.
